# Making a Thread sleep until some other work is done

Tags: java

My application starts, where it will automatically creates some database tables if not exist and creates also some default values in those tables(doing this in background using swingworker). Then the application continues and reads some data from those tables, I need the second process(reading from those tables) to wait for some seconds until the tables are created from previous step.
I've used the Thread.sleep(2000); but it's not accepted in NetBeans as this is heappeing when I'm opening the window like this formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt)
How can I do that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why can't you use `Thread.sleep`? What do you mean by "not accepted"?

Comment: it just underline it in red and give some strange suggestions, and when i write the word Thread. it shows nothing except  the word  class.

Comment: Try to write `try { Thread.sleep(2000); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}` and compile. Then show us the error message.

Comment: same problem, no error message, just the word sleep is underlined in red

Comment: Try another IDE (e.g. Intellij Idea Community Edition).

Comment: could you post screenshot or some code to look at?

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.concurrent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) is more portable than Swing workers.

Using an executor "single threaded" ensure the jobs are sequential, executed as soon as possible.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

class DatabaseLayer {

   private Connection _connection;

   public DatabaseLayer( /* some args here */ ) {
      // _connection = ... use args
      final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      executor.submit( this::create );
      executor.submit( this::read );
   }

   void create() {
      _connection = null;
      System.err.println( "Create database..." );
   }

   void read() {
      System.err.println( "Read database..." );
   }
}

public class Main /* extends swing JFrame or javafx Application */ {

   private DatabaseLayer _dbLayer;

   public void start() {
      _dbLayer = new DatabaseLayer(
         /* get parameters from properties file or command line */);
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      // create user interface from args
   }
}
```

You may use different packages:

- db layer: several classes
- application logic: one per business logic transformation
- presentation: you may choose between desktop (swing or javafx) or web ui

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do it is using CompletableFuture (Java 8), with this API you can chain your execution and still use separate threads -> https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i found an easier way to solve my problem, i just created a JFrame manually in the class which is creating the tables then disposing it after that, like this tha main thread continues normal in a sequentail way.